# Adding MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.Json to recent version of PCL ERROR?

Tags: json, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am trying add reference MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.Json to my PCL project(working with VS 2015 preview).
But it says "could not install package into a project that targets 'portable-net45_win + wpa81+ wp80 _ MonoAndroid10 + MonoTouch 10' but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.

json plug in doesn't support? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Solved.
I just added NewtonSoft.json first then works.